# How to loop through query results and create a new object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using `Laravel 5.5` andd I have a query that is returning data like below (raw query not eloquent).

The order number can be the same for multiple objects (i.e. `164377`). What I need to do is loop through all of the results and create an object for each ordernumber (i.e. `164377`) instead of having multiple objects for each `ordernumber`.

I can't do a `group by` because I need to check each order and if the order number is the same I need to manipulate some properties and this can only be done after I query everything

Data returned as a `JSON` response from the server

```
     {
        "ordernumber": 164377,
        "deliverydate": "2017-11-28 00:00:00",
        "suLN": "60",
        "osLN": "1.4",
        "osStatus": 100,
        "VerifiedOn": null
    },
    {
        "ordernumber": 164377,
        "deliverydate": "2017-11-28 00:00:00",
        "suLN": "76",
        "osLN": "1.4",
        "osStatus": 100,
        "VerifiedOn": null
    },
    {
        "ordernumber": 164377,
        "deliverydate": "2017-11-28 00:00:00",
        "suLN": "61",
        "osLN": "1.4",
        "osStatus": 100,
        "VerifiedOn": null
    },
    {
        "ordernumber": 163868,
        "deliverydate": "2017-11-08 00:00:00",
        "suLN": "94",
        "osLN": "3.8",
        "osStatus": 1300,
        "VerifiedOn": "2017-11-15 06:54:46"
    },
```

controller

```
$data         = DB
              ::connection('s2')
              ->select
              ("
              SELECT
                `wo`.`ordernumber`, `wo`.`deliverydate`, 
                `su`.`ListNumber` as suLN, `os`.`ListNumber` as osLN, `su`.`LineNumber` as suLN, `os`.`LineNumber` as osLN, `os`.`status` as osStatus, 
                `su`.`VerifiedOn`
              FROM
                 `wo`.`orders` AS `wo` 
                 INNER JOIN
                    `pr`.`su` AS `su` 
                    ON `wo`.`ordernumber` = `su`.`ordernumber` 
                 INNER JOIN
                    `pr`.`orderstatus` AS `os` 
                    ON `su`.`FrameNumber` = `os`.`boxnumber` 
                    AND `wo`.`ordernumber` = `os`.`ordernumber` 
              WHERE
                 `wo`.`pID` = ?
              ",
              [$pID]
              );

foreach ($data as $d) {
  // check if object exists or create new object for each $d->ordernumber
    // if object exists check if $d->LineNumber matches
      // if LineNumber matches 
        $d->counter = $d->counter + 1; // new property created 
}

 return response()->json(['data' => $data], 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$new = array();  // Make a new array
foreach ($data as $d) {   // Loop over your data
    $id = $d->ordernumber;  // Get order number for each order
    unset($d->ordernumber);  // Remove order number from object
    $new[$id][] = $d;  // Insert object into new array using ordernumber as key
}
print_r($new);  // Profit!!
```

Output of this is:

```
Array
(
    [164377] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [deliverydate] => 2017-11-28 00:00:00
                    [suLN] => 60
                    [osLN] => 1.4
                    [osStatus] => 100
                    [VerifiedOn] =>
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [deliverydate] => 2017-11-28 00:00:00
                    [suLN] => 76
                    [osLN] => 1.4
                    [osStatus] => 100
                    [VerifiedOn] =>
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [deliverydate] => 2017-11-28 00:00:00
                    [suLN] => 61
                    [osLN] => 1.4
                    [osStatus] => 100
                    [VerifiedOn] =>
                )

        )

    [163868] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [deliverydate] => 2017-11-08 00:00:00
                    [suLN] => 94
                    [osLN] => 3.8
                    [osStatus] => 1300
                    [VerifiedOn] => 2017-11-15 06:54:46
                )

        )

)
```

Now you can loop your new array and if `count === 1` there's only one order for that number, if count > 1 do whatever processing you need to do.